# Вывод сообщения в консоль после загрузки всех изображений в папку

Tags: node.js

Как вывести сообщение в консоль только после того, как в папку загрузятся все изображения?

```
var request  = require('request');
var fs       = require('fs');

function downloadImage() {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.imagesCount; i++) {
    request(data.imagesArray[i])
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('images/file' + i + '.jpg').on('finish', function() {
        console.log('Изображение загружено в папку images')
      }));
  }
  console.log('Все изображения загружены в папку images');
}
```

Comment: Можно попробовать в `.on('finish')` проверять индекс `var i`. `if (i < data.imagesCount - ) console.log('FIN');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
var request  = require('request');
var fs       = require('fs');

function allImagesWereLoaded(){
    console.log('Все изображения загружены в папку images');
}

function downloadImage() {
    var counter = data.imagesCount;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.imagesCount; i++) {
        request(data.imagesArray[i])
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('images/file' + i + '.jpg').on('finish', function() {
                console.log('Изображение загружено в папку images')
                counter--;
                if(counter == 0){
                    allImagesWereLoaded();
                }
            }));
    }
}
```